# Insertar datos a sql server solo si los 3 "insert" resultaron correctos

Tags: c#, transacciones, ado.net

Buenas tardes, actualmente estoy rellenando 3 tablas de mi base de datos, por lo que al momento de conseguir los datos estos son ingresados en la primera tabla, obtengo la primary key del primer insert para luego ocuparlo en el relleno de las siguientes dos, probé mi código y funciona todo perfecto
Mi duda es como puedo hacer para que los registros solo sean insertados si es que los 3 insert fueron exitosamente llevados a cabo, es decir si el primero tuvo error que no continúe con los otros 2 insert o viceversa si es que se insertó todo bien en la primera tabla pero falló el insert de la tabla 3 que no inserte los datos de las 2 primera tablas dado que tendría fallas en mi información dado tales relaciones entre ellas (foráneas). 
Existe una manera de hacerlo? Comparto mi código de igual forma, saludos.

```
public static bool crearPlanificacion(Planificacion recibo)
{
    var query = "INSERT INTO ActividadPlanificada (idActividadGenerica, idSucursalEmpresa,anio, mes,descripcionActividadPlanificada) VALUES" +
        "(@idActividadGenerica,@idSucursalEmpresa,@anio, @mes,@descripcionActividadPlanificada);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(); ";

    var query2 = "INSERT INTO UsuarioEstadoActividadPlanificada (idUsuario, idActividadPlanificada,idEstado) VALUES" +
        "(@idUsuario,@idActividadPlanificada,@idEstado)";

    var query3 = "INSERT INTO UsuarioActividadPlanificada (idUsuario, idActividadPlanificada,fechaAsignacionResponsable) VALUES" +
        "(@idUsuario,@idActividadPlanificada,@fechaAsignacionResponsable)";

    String fechaAsignacionResponsable = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-M-yyyy HH:mm");

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conexionString);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        //TANTAS VECES COMO idActividadGenerica VENGAN DESDE EL CLIENTE
        for (int i = 0; i < recibo.planificacion.Count ; i++)
        {
            //Tabla ActividadPlanificada
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@idActividadGenerica", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = recibo.planificacion[i].idActividadGenerica; //desde array json
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@idSucursalEmpresa", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = recibo.idSucursalEmpresa;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@anio", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = recibo.anio;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@mes", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = recibo.mes;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@descripcionActividadPlanificada", SqlDbType.Text)).Value = recibo.descripcionActividadPlanificada;

            //Ejecutamos la consulta y obtenemos la id de la actividadPlanificada para insertarla en las otras tablas
            Int32 pkActividadPlanificada = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());

            //Tabla UsuarioEstadoActividadPlanificada
            SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(query2, connection);
            command2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@idUsuario", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = recibo.idUsuarioResponsable;
            command2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@idActividadPlanificada", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = pkActividadPlanificada;
            command2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@idEstado", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = 1; //Por defecto empiezan con estado Pendiente
            command2.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //Tabla UsuarioActividadPlanificada
            SqlCommand command3 = new SqlCommand(query3, connection);
            command3.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@idUsuario", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = recibo.idUsuarioResponsable;
            command3.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@idActividadPlanificada", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = pkActividadPlanificada;
            command3.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fechaAsignacionResponsable", SqlDbType.DateTime)).Value = fechaAsignacionResponsable;
            command3.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }                

        connection.Close();                
        return true;                
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso se logra con transacciones. Esto permite ejecutar varias operaciones de forma atómica.

La idea es que haces un `connection.BeginTransaction()` antes de comenzar los inserts. Y solo en caso de que los 3 funcionen, entonces haces un `commit()`. Si el `commit()` no se ejecuta, todos los cambios se descartan.

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(conexionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using(var tx = connection.BeginTransaction())
    {
        // haces tus inserts aquí.

        // si llega hasta aquí sin error, entonces hacemos el commit
        tx.Commit();
    }
}
```

El otro detalle, es que cada vez que creas los `SqlCommand`, debes pasarles tu transacción como parámetro además de la conexión.

O sea que en vez de:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
```

... debes crearlos de esta forma:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection, tx);
```

---

En cuanto a tu pregunta en los comentarios sobre el manejo de errores, estoy convencido que el patrón de ignorar la excepción para luego devolver un `true` o `false` nada más, no es buena práctica.

En mi opinión, la mayoría del código no debería siquiera tener un `try-catch`. Y solo en un lugar muy central, bien arriba en la pila de llamadas, donde tienes la oportunidad de comunicarle algo al usuario, allí sí puedes atrapar el error, y dejarle saber al usuario que algo inusual sucedió, e incluir los detalles del error para poder diagnosticar el problema.

En este caso, yo simplemente definiría el método `crearPlanificacion` como un `void` sin ningún `try-catch`:

```
public static void crearPlanificacion(Planificacion recibo)
{
    // ...
}
```

Y en el lugar donde necesitas decirle al usuario si hubo éxito o no, allí manejas el error. Un ejemplo:

```
try
{
    Planificacion recibo = //...algún código...
    crearPlanificacion(recibo);

    mostrarAlUsuario("Todo funcionó bien!!");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    mostrarAlUsuario($"Algo falló. Detalles del error: {e}.");
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda @sstan pude hacerlo funcionar con tus indicaciones, mi única duda ahora es como manejo los errores, en qué parte del código incluyo un try catch? mi código quedó de la siguiente manera, está bien?: https://codeshare.io/aJQJ4R

Comment: El manejo de errores depende de lo que quieres lograr. En lo personal, me parece mucho mejor no manejar errores que no deberían ocurrir. Por ejemplo, en este caso, yo no incluiría ningún `try-catch`, ni tampoco retornaría un `bool` para indicar éxito o no. Simplemente definiría el método como `void` y si salta una excepción, pues que salte y me dé todos los detalles. Así como lo tienes en tu pregunta, si llegara a suceder un error, te devolvería `false` sin tener idea de la causa del error  porque estás ignorando la excepción. En mi opinión, eso es peligroso.

Comment: lo único que me interesa saber es que la linea  tx.Commit(); se ejecutó, por lo que hubo un registro, la idea de retornar un true o false es para retornarle tal bool a un dispositivo movil que realiza el ingreso y así desde el movil con ese true o false pueda mostrar que se insertó bien o no, y tengo entendido que con un void no lo podría saber, disculpa si me equivoco, por eso no sé donde colocar el return false.. lo que se me ocurre sería remplazar la linea del commit por un if(tx.Commit()){ return true;}else{return false;}

Comment: Agregué a la respuesta lo que yo considero buena práctica en cuanto a manejo de errores.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda! Ahora si todo perfecto, muy agradecido, saludos

Comment: @Kako si la excelente respuesta de sstan te ayudó, considera marcarla como aceptada. Asi indicas a otros que puedan tener tu mismo problema que esta respuesta es la adecuada. Un saludo.

Comment: @pikoh gracias! soy nuevo por aqui, no sabia de eso, pero ya lo hice, saludos